# Could you teach me the meaning of this sentence " I'll make you up another rhyme "?

Tags: sentence-meaning

A little mouse got a rug from a woman. He was so pleased he sang this song.

> "Oh me, oh my!
>
> We'll soon be as snug
>
> As a bug in a rug
>
> What do you think of that!
>
> Come and see me any time
>
> **I'll make you up another rhyme**
>
> But please don't bring the cat."

This is a short story from "Little Old Mrs Pepperpot".

I couldn't understand this sentence "I'll make you up another rhyme". Does it mean "I will make up another rhyme for you?

Comment: I think you're correct about "I'll make up another rhyme for you". Do remember, in figurative speech (in this example, poetry) word order can be changed for effect. In this case, the author's probably changed it around so that "rhyme" rhymes with "time".

Comment: @JamesWirth Could you write an answer?

Comment: As with other ditransitive phrasal verbs, if ***make up*** has an indirect object (***you***, in this case), this can appear *between* the two words. So *I'll make up a sandwich for you, I'll cut off a slice for you* can be rephrased as *I'll make you up a sandwich, I'll cut you off a slice*.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Thank you for your comment. How about a direct object? For example, can I rephrased I'll make up a sandwich for you as I'll make a sandwich up for you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "Make up a sandwich" ? That must be a uniquely BrE expression, because I have never heard it used that way in AmE.

Comment: @Gandalf: Feasibly it's uniquely BrE, but I kinda doubt it. It's essentially the same usage as [She made him up a bed](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22she+made+him+up+a+bed%22) (which I assume you *have* heard in AmE).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Actually, it's only make + object with both in AmE. We teach both as collocations with only "make" in EFL. make a bed, make a sandwich, make a bet, etc. PS: "make up a bed" and "make a bed" have different meanings.

Comment: @Gandalf: I realise including ***up*** conveys a nuance of difference when *making [up] a bed*, but you seem not to recognise that much the same nuance applies when *making [up] a sandwich*. Which is *not* just some quirk of BrE - if you switch to the BrE corpus on [make up a sandwich](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+up+a+sandwich&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20up%20a%20sandwich%3B%2Cc0) there aren't enough hits to chart - so obviously *most* of them must be AmE.

Comment: @Gandalf - We could make up a sandwich for *you*, as in, invent "The Gandalf", featuring all of your favourite sandwich ingredients. It'll be biggest thing since the grilled cheese...

Comment: @nnnnnn I understand the use of "make up" as "invent": it's the same as in the OP's question. What I did not understand is why it would be used in an example for a learner when it is not a common usage and might even lead the OP to think it was the correct usage of the phrasal verb as in "to prepare a sandwich". I thought it required clarification. If there is some other "nuance" of meaning which escapes me I wish someone would explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your passage

> I'll make you up another rhyme

does mean

> I will make up another rhyme for you

The idiom is

> *verb* + *someone* + up

where the action (verb+up) is being done for/to *someone*

> I'll fix you up a sandwich.
>   *I'll make a sandwich for you*
>
> They'll write her up in the paper.
>   *They'll write a story about her in the paper*
>
> We'll cook him up some dinner.
>   *We'll cook something for dinner for him*
>
> Let's rustle ourselves up some grub.
>   *Let's get some food (in cowboy speak)*